# PHP Preg_replace placeholders

Tags: php, regex

Hi I'm writing something for handling my views an I need a preg_replace here, but i can't seem to get it working so I've scrapped the code.

the strings I am trying to replace are dynamic based on a template, e.g.

`{{name}} is {{age}} years old`

And the passed information into the function is an array e.g.

`array(
  'name' => 'John Doe',
  'age' => '27'
);`

The pattern I have so far is `\{{([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\}}` however this only seems to match one pair of braces.

I'm also having a problem looping through results in preg_match_all..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`preg_replace_callback` seems like a good candidate.

```
$str = "{{name}} is {{age}} years old";
$values = array( 'name' => 'John Doe', 'age' => '27' );
echo preg_replace_callback("/\{{([a-z0-9]+?)\}}/i", function ($result)
use ($values) {
   if (isset($result[1])) {
      return $values[$result[1]];
   }
}, $str);
```

The main issue is that `{{[a-z]+}}` will match from `{{name ... age}}`.  Using the `?` makes the `+` reluctant so it only matches up to the *first* `}` rather than the last.

Comment: I don't think non-greedy makes a difference at all, `}` is _not_ in `[a-z]` right? I made a quick JS demo, but it should apply for PHP as well: http://jsbin.com/ayugew/1/edit

Comment: @elclanrs good point, it's not necessary.  I'm not sure what his original problem was exactly; maybe just using `preg_match_all` incorrectly.

Comment: I fixed the issue but yours was the best answer so accepted yours.

Answer (score 1):

> ...however this only seems to match one pair of braces.

You forgot the escape the second `{`

```
/\{\{([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\}\}/
  -^-               -^-
```

In any case, try this regex, it's a bit shorter:

```
/\{\{([^}]+)\}\}/
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use `sprintf`?

```
$template = '%s is %d years old';
$vars = array('name' => 'John Doe', 'age' => 27);
$output = sprintf($template, $vars['name'], $vars['age']);
```

Comment: Ideally want to avoid having to create that array and replace based on what the templates have inside them, essentially this is for a kind of server side angular.js Thanks for the input.